# How can a client deal with "unable to create new native thread exception" on the client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, out-of-memory

I have a chat application(Socket Programming) , for that consider I have 2 separate chat servers 'Server1'  & 'Server2' .
I am using 2 chat servers to for load balancing(Lvs). My LVS is working fine.

For example: When 1000 users at a time  tries to login , with the effect of LVS, 500 requests goes to 'server1' and other 500 to 'server2'.

Here comes my problem: When I am trying to login for 5000 users , after around 4850 successful login, I am getting error  :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

on 'Client side'.

How should I deal with this?

For reference: i am using newfixedthreadpool ,
Here is part of login that I am using on server side and client side.

On server side:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(400);
while(true){
    s = ss.accept(); 
}
```

On login side

```
for(int i=startc;i<endc;i++) // here for e.g if we want to login 1000 users, startc value =1 and endc value=1000.
    {
        ChatClient.chatHandler  = new ChatClient("users"+i);
    }

ChatClient {

public ChatClient(String username)
    {
        Chatclient = this;
        this.username = username;   
        LoginChatConnect();
    }
}

void LoginchatConnect(){
try{
    sockChatListen  = new Socket(URLstore.serverSocket,URLstore.ChatPort); // chatPort=5004,serverSocket=server Ip address.
}catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in LoginChat "+e);
        }
}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking how should the client handle that the server is running out of memory?  I'm not sure it can since chances are it won't get a notification of that failure.

Comment: yes, at client side I want to avoid this exception. means there is a way to handle this situation.?

Comment: Is the exception happening on the client side or the server side?  Which VM is running out of memory?  This is not something that you can just "handle".

Comment: exception is happening on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what are you trying to do is, you are testing your server application i.e. chat server by running test application i.e. client . now you must be running that particular code in loop . this loop of yours giving you outofmemory exception, which is obvious. if you will keep on running code in infinite loop its bound to go outofmemory.

i will suggest to run the loop in finite for loop like run it for 4000 times on one client machine and  you can run multiple test code on many client machines. run the test client on different machine for example each client running loop for 4000 times and such clients you are running on 4 different machines. so output will be, your client test code will not fail because of outofmemory exception and you will be able to test your server application for 16k user logins..

it should work

Answer (score 0):

Obviously increasing the `-Xmx` argument to `java` will give your application more memory but I'm not sure that is what you are asking.

```
 # start our java program with 2 gigabyte of core memory
 java -Xmx2g ...
```

Typically if a JVM gets this exception it is a *critical error*.  As load drops back down it may be able to recover but any call to allocate a `new` object may have thrown, which would effect data caches, automations, etc..  Usually a restart of the application is necessary.

When this condition is happening, it is going to be extremely difficult for the process to let a remote process know that it is out of memory.  Any network operation would probably generate additional memory allocations that most likely will fail.  It can certainly be watching it's memory levels and when it reaches 95% it could start sending out warnings, but this is a very inexact science given that garbage collection may free a large percentage of memory in the next second.

We have internal JVM monitors which start warning with the old-gen space gets above some level but this is for our operations screens only.  False positives are common here.  Only if that level stays above the warning level for a period of time do we investigate.